# Why do the default PHP Joomla! files get restored without asking?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, default

I edited the `\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php` file to suit my needs, and to output a customized string instead of the default H1 header. The site was running all OK, but *when I created a new menu item that I needed*, using the backend admin interface, **I lost the PHP file `default.php` modifications**, and it got restored to its initial values. Why did this happen?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please take our [tour] and consider giving your account a more "human" name.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hard time believing that the file was updated when creating a new menu item. It was more likely updated when updating Joomla. And that is expected. You should never modify core files, they will be overwritten when updating.

Instead you should create a copy of the template and then create layout overrides. There is plenty of documentation regarding this topic:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides